# Can you import python libaries into microPython?

Tags: python, microcontroller, micropython

I have started a project and to test if it works, I used a Pi zero. It has buttons and then sends MIDI Messages to my PC, depending on what buttons are pressed. So a simple MIDI Controller.

Now I think that a Microcontroller, like the Pico would be better suitable for such a task, but it can only run MicroPython.

So my question is, wether you can import most or all of the python libaries into microPython or if I should use another MicroController that can run python.

Comment: A microcontroller running MicroPython should be easily capable of acting as a simple MIDI controller. If you want a good answer though, please ask a more focused question with more specific details about your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is, wether you can import most or all of the python libaries into microPython or if I should use another MicroController that can run python.

While MicroPython shares much of the syntax of Python (3.4), it is different enough that anything but the most trivial Python code will not run under MicroPython. In general, you should only expect to run code developed explicitly for MicroPython on a MicroPython capable device.

> So my question is, wether you can import most or all of the python
> libaries into microPython or if I should use another MicroController
> that can run python.

I don't believe there are any microcontrollers available that can run standard Python. The smallest device you're going to find is probably something like the Raspberry Pi Zero.

Comment: Actually the most common default Python libraries, are also available in MicroPython. Moreover some of them have already been optimized for MicroPython. You can tell by the "u" at the start of their name.

Comment: And those libraries generally don't behave identically to their Python counterparts. E.g., if you any non trivial code that works with the `socket` library, it will probably fail with `usocket`. The MicroPython versions have fewer available methods, are often missing a variety of attributes, and behave differently from their Python counterparts.

Comment: Still, the answer to the first part of the question is "you can import some python libraries in MicroPython". And if the module is behaving differently or has fewer attributes, it's because it has been modified to run on Microcontrollers.

Answer (score 1):

Usually "no."  It won't fit.